# Solidworks Installing: Executable file did not installed

Tags: installation, executable, solidworks

I just installing my Solidowrks. But after only 2%, it shows a notification as following:

The executable file "C:\Pradipta\SOLIDWORKS\SolidWorks 2020 SP5.0 (TI ITB LICENSE)\SOLIDWORKS 2020 SP5.0\64bit\MSSQLServer\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe" /ConfigurationFile="C:\ProgramData\SOLIDWORKS Electrical\SWSQLSetup.ini" /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Q /SAPWD=SQLpwd4ew /AGTSVCPASSWORD=SQLpwd4ew did not install successfully.

What are the possible solution to encounter this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the correct forum for installations questions.
but i would strongly suggest you contact your Solidworks Reseller, and ask them for further help with the installation.

That being said; i sometimes see issues with the SQL-Express that is included in the Solidworks installation package; and my go-to workaround has always been simply installing a SQL-Express manually first, and then during the SW-installation, point to that.

Comment: Did you have any success with the manual SQL-Express install?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following path **`\SolidWorks.2023.SP1.0.Premium.DVD\PreReqs\SQLServer`**

 Open the `sqlsetup.ini` in a notepad and add the following.

```
IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS="Yes"
```